# My 'price' variable of my parser is stuck on the first price it parsed

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

i coded a parser, this one :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.nike.com/fr/w/hommes-chaussures-nik1zy7ok').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

csv_file = open('nikeshoes.csv', 'w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['name', 'price', 'image_scr'])

for pair in soup.find_all('div', class_='product-card__body'):

    name = pair.a.text
    print(name)

    price = soup.find('div', class_='product-price css-11s12ax is--current-price').text
    print(price)

    try:
        image_scr = pair.select_one('img.css-1fxh5tw.product-card__hero-image')['src']
    except Exception as e:
        image_scr = None
    print(image_scr)

    print()
    csv_writer.writerow([name, price, image_scr])

csv_file.close()
```

The names and images links works fine and i get all of them but the `price` variable seems to be stuck on the first price of the web page, as shown bellow

[image]

It is weird because when i look through the website the price change in the html path i use.
Does someone would know why the price is stuck on the first item ?

Comment: Try changing "price = soup.find" to "price = pair.find"

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

> At this point and until the end of the list the price cannot be found also it is the same path.

Not really, there is a sale price and a regular price and structure of elements and classes is sligthly different -> Your selection wont work.

#### How to fix?

Select your elements more specific for example by `attribute`:

```
regular_price = pair.select_one('div[data-test="product-price"]').text.replace(u'\xa0', u' ') if pair.select('div[data-test="product-price"]') else None
```

You should also check, if element is available or not.

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.nike.com/fr/w/hommes-chaussures-nik1zy7ok').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

data = []
for pair in soup.find_all('div', class_='product-card__body'):

    name = pair.a.text.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
    regular_price = pair.select_one('div[data-test="product-price"]').text.replace(u'\xa0', u' ') if pair.select('div[data-test="product-price"]') else None
    sale_price= pair.select_one('div[data-test="product-price-reduced"]').text.replace(u'\xa0', u' ') if pair.select('div[data-test="product-price-reduced"]') else None

    try:
        image_src = pair.select_one('img.css-1fxh5tw.product-card__hero-image')['src']
    except Exception as e:
        image_src = None
    
    data.append({
        'name':name,
        'regular_price':regular_price,
        'sale_price':sale_price,
        'image_src':image_src
    })

data
```